# How to finalize Shopping Cart, Save user_id and product_id of a session to databse

Tags: session, cakephp, authentication, cart

I have a doubt, my sistem have selected products to shopping card, but I would like to know how can I get User_id and all selected product_id, I have a session named

['Auth']['user']['id'] and ['Cart']['']['product']['id']

how can I save into database?

Thanks for everything!https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCV9O.png

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to write a novel about that so just check the code. There is a bunch more to consider than just saving the data to the database.

https://github.com/burzum/Cart

Also read the section "[Saving your data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html)" of the [CakePHP book](http://book.cakephp.org). It should be logical that you have to read the data from your session and save it to the database. The page tells you how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna explain a litle about my question, I have a shopping Card allready and does every thing except payment because I don't need to include payment, is a system for control books at my school.

for each user, I want to get its Id and its prosucts selectd.

exemple: (I have 2 tables, users and products), when user finalizes the shopping cart, I need to store in table below, her id and selected products ids

Here I have a new table to store Products for each users

|used_id   | product_id|
| 2013101  | 201340    |
| 2013101  | 201334    |
| 2013102  | 201395    |
| 2013102  | 201399    |

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna explain a litle about my question, I have a shopping Card allready and does every thing except payment because I don't need to include payment, is a system for control books at my school.

for each user, I want to get its Id and its prosucts selectd.

exemple: (I have 2 tables, users and products), when user finalizes the shopping cart, I need to store in table below, her id and selected products ids

Here I have a new table to store Products for each users 
***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***
| used_id  | product_id|
***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***
| 2013101  | 201340    |
| 2013101  | 201334    |
| 2013102  | 201395    |
| 2013102  | 201399    |
***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***